# Run UE5 server as a windows-service with regular win tools

Tags: windows, deployment, service, windows-services, unreal-engine5

There was a need for the deployment of the Unreal Engine server (v5.1.1) to start it as a windows service on win10.

An attempt to package it through the regular Windows service tool (`sc create...`) resulted in the UE process being started (it can be observed in the task manager), however, the service launch is not successful and crashes with `error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`.

I must say right away that increasing the timeout in the register does not help.

The second point, packaging through the `nssm` utility is successful. However, `nssm` replaces the `exe` file in the service with its own, and this is undesirable for us.

What can be the reason for the unsuccessful launch after using `sc`, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: You can't run just any binary as a service; it has to adhere to a contract: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have experienced, SC will happily install any executable file as a service. However, that executable will only start if it is a "true" Windows Service — one that includes code to integrate with the Windows Services Manager (SCM).

Since Unreal Engine server is not a Windows Service, any attempt to start your service will always generate [Error 1053](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#Error1053).

There is no way to fix that failure without using a [service wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_wrapper). If NSSM isn't working for you, [Microsoft Srvany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service) (basic but functional) and [WinSW](https://github.com/winsw/winsw) are other free options that may do the trick.